# image Url to base64encode?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How convert image url into base64encode in jquery? For example image url convert to binary to pass another page

Comment: How to convert the image URL or the image itself?

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do something plain javascript does without added fat.

Comment: You don't need to encode an url in base64 just to pass it to another page. Maybe have a look at [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: `base64_encode` = JavaScript's [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa).

Comment: btoa/atob could only be used in webkit and moz ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Base64 encoding/decoding class http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html. I don't think jquery has it included.